# exiting infinte loop

Tags: bash

This code gets into an infinite loop. How can in troubleshoot it?

```
PGM=ot_run_hourly
PID=$$
TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
MASTER_DATE_STAMP_BEGIN=`date +%D`
MASTER_TIME_STAMP_BEGIN=`date +%T`
DIR=/var/opt/gogd/ship/na/log

#logfiles /var/opt/gogd/ship/na/log/ot_run_hourly*.log

LOG_FILE=${DIR}/${PGM}_${TIMESTAMP}_${PID}.log
COUNTER=1

date +"Info: %m/%d/%Y %T : Step 1 : Start" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}

while [ $COUNTER -le 5 ]
do

        date +"Info: %m/%d/%Y %T : Step 2 : Counter $COUNTER" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}



        COUNTER =`expr $COUNTER + 1`

        sleep 60

done

date +"Info: %m/%d/%Y %T : Step 3 : Complete" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}/var/opt/gogd/ship/scripts
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the following line:

```
COUNTER =`expr $COUNTER + 1`
```

You have a space after `COUNTER`.  You should have seen an error saying:

```
bash: COUNTER: command not found
```

Say:

```
COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
```

instead, or better still

```
COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
```

Comment: I prefer it even shorter: `((COUNTER++))`.

Comment: Fair enough, I seem to have missed part of the conversation here. Never mind, lets delete this conversation (which I started), we're not adding anything useful to the post.

Answer (score 2):

The way to **troubleshoot** this is by executing the commands before the while loop in a interactive shell, the same that you use to execute this command.

Skip the while statement and then copy and paste

```
date +"Info: %m/%d/%Y %T : Step 2 : Counter $COUNTER" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
```

and then

```
COUNTER =`expr $COUNTER + 1`
```

while checking what the shell tells you `COUNTER: command not found` and you will notice that `echo $COUNTER` still gives `1` and never increases. That should give you an idea on where to start looking what to fix.